# Strange "Edited Post" text at end of title can't be removed

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits

At the time I am writing this, the title of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978461/find-nth-largest-integer-within-two-sorted-arrays-using-divide-and-conquer-algor) ends with the words "Edited Post". When I attempt to edit the post to remove those words, the edit fails with an error message that "a question with that title already exists". The post has no edit history (it has never been edited).

Expected: Able to remove those words from title and save edit.

Actual: Edit fails with error mentioned above. Words cannot be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've created two copies of roughly the same question in the past hour:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978132/find-nth-largest-integer-within-two-sorted-arrays-using-divide-and-conquer-algor

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978461/find-nth-largest-integer-within-two-sorted-arrays-using-divide-and-conquer-algor

[The one you're trying to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978461/find-nth-largest-integer-within-two-sorted-arrays-using-divide-and-conquer-algor) should probably be closed as a duplicate of [the one you're not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978132/find-nth-largest-integer-within-two-sorted-arrays-using-divide-and-conquer-algor) (and probably improved to not just be a "here's my code, what's the problem?" question).

Comment: I didn't create either of those questions -- but anyways, yeah that explains it. I didn't notice a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonC Sorry, I just assumed the question was yours.